# Varying marker label gaps for individual observations

Tags: label, stata, marker

I know that I can vary marker position using `mlabv()` and creating a position variable for individual points on my `twoway scatter` plot.

Is there a way to do a similar thing for `mlabgap()`?

I am trying to have certain points' labels a little further away from the rest to avoid overprinting.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?marker_label_options implies that the gap is constant in each graph call.

That does not rule out e.g.

```
scatter y x if group == 1. mlabel(foo) mlabgap(1) ///
|| scatter y x if group == 2, mlabel(foo) mlabgap(2)
```

Another trick is adding spaces as prefix or suffix to the marker label variable in various observations as needed.